# bash: How to grep ip4 address

Tags: regex, bash, awk, ip

I work on a Mac OS.
I'm trying to grep all foreign addresses communicating with my PC by `netstat`. So I write a bash script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex_ip="(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}"
netstat -an | awk -v regex="$regex_ip" 'match($5, regex){print $1 " " $5 " " $6}'
```

To my surprise, the result of the script includes something that I don't understand:

```
tcp4 209.58.188.104.443 ESTABLISHED
tcp4 209.58.188.104.443 ESTABLISHED
tcp4 209.58.188.104.443 ESTABLISHED
tcp4 17.252.156.146.5223 ESTABLISHED
tcp4 209.58.188.104.443 ESTABLISHED
tcp4 121.51.140.151.443 ESTABLISHED
tcp4 192.168.1.107.63705 ESTABLISHED
udp4 203.208.43.65.443 
8ed9d67a97a634bf 8ed9d67aa16641d7 0
8ed9d67a93d2faf7 8ed9d67a9568389f 0
8ed9d67a93d3100f 8ed9d67a954e2a8f 0
8ed9d67a93d3006f 8ed9d67a94062fe7 0
8ed9d67a93d30f47 8ed9d67a94062b0f 0
8ed9d67a93d30e7f 8ed9d67a94062eef 0
8ed9d67a93d30137 8ed9d67a940321d7 0
8ed9d67a93d30db7 8ed9d67a9401ff6f 0
8ed9d67a93d30c27 8ed9d67a93f8e7a7 0
8ed9d67a93d30b5f 8ed9d67a93d2a89f 0
```

As you see I got two parts: ip4 addresses and something about UDP diagrams (if I am correct).

I don't understand why the `$regex_ip` doesn't work as excepted: How could things like `8ed9d67a9568389f` match the regex? What I need is only those ip4 addresses.

The output of `netstat -an`:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you post sample output as a text not as picture?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  Done.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  You mean the output of `netstat -an`?

Comment: ... of course ... cause that will be a real testable fragment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  I captured parts of output

Comment: ok, try my approach

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  Great, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX you can add `-p tcp` as protocol to get only `tcp4` output:

```
{ netstat -an -p tcp; netstat -an -p udp; } | 
awk -v regex="$regex_ip" '$5 ~ regex{print $1, $5, $6}'
```

Also as @triplee mentioned as single quotes in your regex and use double escaping of dot. So use:

```
regex_ip='(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\\.(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}'
```

Comment: Well, in fact I need the ip of UDP too so I can't add `-p tcp`. I just copy your code but the problem is still there.

Comment: `{ netstat -an -p tcp; netstat -an -p udp; } | awk -v regex="$regex_ip" '$5 ~ regex{print $1, $5, $6}'` should work. It works for me on my OSX

Comment: Without `-p tcp` and `-p udp`, `netstat` will be returning "all" kind of stats that includes steam, datagram records.

Comment: So it's the problem of `netstat -an`?

Comment: In a way, yes because by default it shows all kind of stats and you need to use some filtering using `-p` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Optimized **`awk`** solution:

```
regex_ip="(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])"
netstat -an | awk -v re="$regex_ip" '$5~"^"re"(\\."re"){3}"{ print $1,$5,$6 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

In double quotes, you need to double the backslash to embed one literally. It's generally a better idea to use single quotes for regular expressions, for exactly this reason.

Comment: You might want to add anchors around the regex, too.